# Add if statement to do-end block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, erb

I've rewritten my html code with rails `content_tag`s and now I want to add if-statements to them.

Before I had:

```
<% if ... %>
    <div class='...'>
    ...
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Now I have 2 types of this block:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, ..., class: 'some_class') if ... %>
```

This works ok. But when I try to add if-statement to `do-end` block it fails:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, class: 'some_class') if ... do %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

I'm seeing this, instead of `div` content:

```
<div>{:class=>"some_class"}</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use like :

```
<%if ... %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, class: 'some_class') do %>
    ...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or using if statement after the block :

```
<%= content_tag(:div, class: 'some_class') do %>
    ...
<% end if .......%>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<%= content_tag(:div, class: 'some_class')  do %>
    ...
<% end if ... %>
```